# SAS between observations from another table search

Tags: sas

```
create table Mstr_codes_frm_thru as
select DISTINCT 
code,value_from,value_thru
from master_code;
```

the from and thru values are housed in a diff table (Exp_Master)

what i would like is a way that i could create a table that would bring back all the observations between the from - thru values along with the code associated with them. (see below)

[image]

Comment: You've show some (or all) of 'master_code' structure, what are the columns in `exp_master`? What is the name of the column in `exp_master` that holds values such as `O31.13X2`

Answer (score 0):

You might want a join that uses the `from` and `thru` from `master_code` as parts of a  `BETWEEN` criteria.

Example:

```
data master_code;
input code min max; datalines;
1 10 12
1 20 22
2 88 91
3 11 14
4 20 21
;
data exp_master;
do code = 1 to 10;
  do value = 1 to 100;
    output;
  end;
end;
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select distinct exp_master.code, exp_master.value, master_code.min, master_code.max
  from master_code 
  join exp_master
  on master_code.code = exp_master.code
  where
  exp_master.value between master_code.min and master_code.max
  ;
quit;
```

[image]